# How to port an existing angular app to electron?

Tags: angularjs, electron

I am a beginner to angular and a complete noob to electron. I was wondering if it would be possible to port an existing angular app to electron by using most of the existing codebase of the webapp?

I found a couple of links on this but not much on Google. Most results talk about starting with angular and electron to create a desktop app - which is my intention but I would like to use most of my existing code base and ideally just add webpack and electron related config to compile the electon app from existing codebase as I don't want to maintain two version of the same codebase.

I could use this bridge to access Electron API (although I am not sure how it will all hang together)
https://github.com/develephant/ngElectron

What do usually people do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also interested in it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to add Electron to an existing AngularJS app.
1. Clone an existing Angular app `git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git`.
2. `cd angular-seed`.
3. `npm install --save electron`.
4. In /app, create a main.js file and paste:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

5. In /app, create a blank renderer.js file.
6. In root of package.json add `"main": "main.js"`.
7. In "scripts" section of package.json change "start" to `"start": "electron ."`.
8. `npm install && npm start`.

Comment: I am getting ERROR!  "Unable to find Electron app at  c:/PROJECT_FOLDER   Cannot find module c:/PROJECT_FOLDER".

Comment: In my case it also works without adding  renderer.js file.

Comment: sry maybe I missed something. where is connection with "existing app" ?

Comment: angular-seed is an existing app on GitHub. This process will create an Electron app from it.

Comment: Worked for me when I changed #6 to "main": "app/main.js"

Comment: I have my own angular app, located in src/app.  Changed #6 to "main": "src/app/main.js" and this brought up an empty electron app, not mine.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at .....
What's next?

Answer (score 1):

loadURL path should be dist folder index.html, Please check your folder path properly, other wise appilication will load empty

```
 mainWindow.loadURL('dist/index.html')
```