# Convert Angular Framework Application to desktop application using Electron

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, node.js, electron

**Project Description:**

---

I have a functional front-end angularjs application that communicates with another back-end Java application deployed in **tomcat** running on different port(8443). I have been running it on a web browser but now i want to run it as a desktop application. I have been running it as `grunt serve` for development environment and `grunt --clean --prod` for production and distribution.
When run in *dev* mode using `grunt serve`, the application runs on http://localhost:9000/?baseApiUrl=https://localhost:8443&tenantIdentifier=demo

**Question:**

---

How do i go about making the application run in electron for *dev* mode and later package it for production? I tried [How to port an existing angular app to electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708419/how-to-port-an-existing-angular-app-to-electron) but it can't communication with the backed application on the port.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how,**

---

**1.** The boilerplate code.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow = null;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  //Take note of this line.
  //mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:9000`);

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
 }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

---

**2.** Take note of the line `mainWindow.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/index.html')`. 
Since your use case is to communicate with another backend application running on a port, using the ***file*** protocol (`file://<uri>`) won't work,  you need to communicate with the port on http protocol.

---

**3.** To achieve this, I suggest to run a static files http server in your electron application, server your app over local server, and replace this `mainWindow.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/index.html')` line with `` mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:9000`) `` this.

**Edit 1:** 
You can run a very basic static files server like so, however there certainly are better ways to write it.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
server.listen(9000);
```

---

**Edit 2:**

After some discussion in the comments, I decided to clone the repo and add the **electron** part myself, here's how I did it.

**1.** Install the following dependencies by running,

```
npm install --save electron express
```

**2.** index.js file

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow = null;

var express = require('express');
var server = express();
let dir = path.join(__dirname, './dist/community-app');
server.use('/', express.static(dir));
server.listen(9000);

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:9000`);

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
    });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

**3.** Add the following script in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
//...
  "start": "electron ."
 },
```

**4.** Result

[image]

PS: I had some troubles building angularjs project, because there were no build scripts in the project for windows, hence some styles are missing from the page.

**Git repo:**

https://github.com/openMF/community-app

Comment: You can paste it right under the boilerplate code, and it should work. And of course, make sure to include express to your dependencies, it is not nodejs built-in module.

Comment: Cant tell the exact problem until I see the code. Perhaps you have a git repo or something where I can inspect?

Comment: On it. Please delete the last comment, and do not ever share credentials in an open setting like this. Look for merge requests on the git repo. @IppezRobert

Comment: Hi Nishkal Kashyap, to build the project please follow this instruction from README.MD file github.com/openMF/community-app/blob/develop/README.md and kindly send the PR to my github report https://github.com/Ippezrobert/community-app

Comment: I have already posted a very elaborate answer, what more do you expect?

Comment: Sorry but i tried the above solution and didn't work my side. i was expecting you to help me send a PR that worked at your side to my GitHub fork github.com/Ippezrobert/community-app

Comment: is there any possible to connect angular electron request to node server

Comment: @NishkalKashyap, can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108769/angular-electron-with-nodejs-using-mean-stack