# Angular Electron with Nodejs using (MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, angular6

I have create a MEAN Stack Application (Angular 6).
Now I want to convert my application into Desktop Application with the same.
we can achieve that in electron so that i read this [Article](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/). by using this Article I have created my application. but I am not get request from the application to server(node.js).

here is my angular req:

```
postlogindata(body: any): Observable<any> {

    return this._http.post(`http://192.168.1.174:8085/login`, body, {
      observe:'body',
     withCredentials :true,
      headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')
    });
  }
```

here I'm receiving the request in Node `server.js` page

```
app.post('/login', UserConfig.loginVerify);
```

**cors origin config**

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:8085','http://192.168.1.174:8085', 'http://127.0.0.1:4200'],
    credentials: true
}));
```

in web application I didn't get any error. but in desktop application i'm getting this error in my console.
[image]
I have read many articles i didn't get any answer.

can anyone explain to me how to resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I am not get request from the application to server(node.js)"? Are you getting any error? if so, what? It really sounds like a CORS issue to me.

Comment: I din't get any error. it is not redirecting. i didn't get any request in node.js.

Comment: That's a post request it is not meant to redirect. Enable the electron developer tools (developer console) so that you can check what is wrong with that and check the console error. I suspect it's a CORS issue, since electron have a built-in proxy.

Comment: @briosheje, Here I have added my cors origin details. can you check it

Comment: just enable the developer console. Electron wraps a browser inside a form, that browser is hosted locally by eletron which builds a web server to do so. All requests sent by that browser are proxied from electron's middleware, hence the request is likely coming from.. I guess localhost:8080, I think that's the default for electron, but I'm not sure. Just enable the developer console and provide the error, otherwise it's really hard to give any further help.

Comment: @briosheje, I have changed my port to 8080, and also I am facing the error. I have updated my question can you check it.

Comment: Your server is refusing the connection, where is your endpoint located?

Comment: this is where I'm sending the req. \src\app\login.  my end point is in outside of this path \src\app\login which is root folder.